# ReactJS - Elegant way to toggle state

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple show / hide style that needs to toggle on a click event. Here is what I have:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {iover: 'hide'}
  }

  handleClick(event) {  
    // this is wrong, it returns a true or false    
    this.setState({ iover: !this.state.iover });
    // this doesn't toggle
    // this.setState({ iover: this.state.iover = 'hide' ? this.state.iover = 'show' : this.state.iover ='hide' });
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

I want to toggle this.state.iover value between 'show' & 'hide'.

What would be the most elegant way to do so.

Comment: You are pretty close to getting it. `this.setState( { iover: this.state.iover == 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide' } );`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with, was hoping for something shorter:

```
    handleClick(event) {
      let show = this.state.iover;
      let index = show.indexOf('show');

      if (index != -1) {
          show = 'hide';
      } else {
          show = 'show';
      }

      this.setState({ iover: show });
      event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: This one is deprecated, see the answer from Christianzamar

Answer (score 16):

One way to do this is to keep your state as a boolean true or false then put a ternary operator wherever you want the value "hide" or "show".
For example:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      iover: false
    };
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({
      iover: !this.state.iover
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className={this.state.iover ? 'show' : 'hide'}>...</div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: as @cristianzamar pointed out, you should never set new state based on current state this way, use


`this.setState(prevState => ({
  iover: !prevState.iover
}));`

instead.

Thats because `setState` is async

Answer (score 7):

I think that @mark-anderson's answer is the most "elegant" way, however, the recommended way of doing a state toggling (according to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)) is:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  iover: !prevState.iover
}));
```

*If you *need* to store 'show/hide' inside that state, the code would be:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  iover: prevState.iover === 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide'
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this was a little challenge for me but I ended up like this --

```
class Toggle extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleToggleVisib = this.handleToggleVisib.bind(this);
    this.state = {
         visib : false 
    }
}

handleToggleVisib(){
    this.setState({ visib : !this.state.visib });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Toggle Built</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleToggleVisib}>
        {this.state.visib? 'Hide Button' : 'Show Button'}
        </button>
        <div>
        {this.state.visib && <p>This is a tough challenege</p>}
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<Toggle />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: If you use handle ToggleVisib = () => {..}, than you don't need to bind.this

Answer (score 0):

There's a really handy little utility for React called classnames (https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

It lets you conditionally render a class, which you can use to handle add the style you need for hiding/showing.

For example, here I'm toggling the state with a function:

```
state = {
    isOpen: false
}

toggleDropdown = () => {
    const toggledIsOpen = this.state.isOpen ? false : true;

    this.setState({
        isOpen: toggledIsOpen
    });
}
```

Then, in the onClick handler for my dropdown , I use classnames to either print class="dropdown" or class="dropdown is-open":

```
// conditionally add 'is-open' class for styling purposes
   const openClass = classNames("dropdown", {
        "is-open": isOpen
   });


return (
    <div className={openClass} onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>[dropdown contents here]</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {iover: false}
}

updateState = () {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    iover: !prevState.iover
  }));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className={this.state.iover ? 'show' : 'hide'}>...</div>
  );
}
```